# Why is web app not loading inside the MS-Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have deployed a simple web app and deployed to https://rockdove.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com:82/. This page has the link to teams app sdk and also has initialized the teams app. im trying to load it inside teams app in my organization using this manifest file. i can upload and install the app but the app is not loading. The index file and manifest used for test is attached here.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to look at:

1. I don't think you can pass anything to `microsoftTeams.initialize()`, so remove the 'window' parameter
2. I've not tested whether the 'validDomains' allows custom ports, but it might not - try put the entry without the ':82', and then also remove entries 2 & 3, so it's only 'rockdove.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com'

Comment: i tried this, still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've just loaded your page directly in the browser, and I think I see the issue - check the basic browser errors - "Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.7.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'pvA9+SJHyjwzeV6CsrvHKjBG3YLc7BedKEGwramv7HU='. The resource has been blocked."

Comment: so looks like you reference to microsoft teams js library is invalid. Maybe it's the hash from a previous version?

Comment: yeah i tried many things so i messed it up- had added 1.5 version checksum in there. now i have updated it and the error is gone.. but still app doesn't get load in my teams, the only error in MS-Teams console is **0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114 2020-09-22T11:51:47.409Z embedded-page-container: Timeout while waiting for iframe to load** @Hilton Giesenow

Comment: I've just tried your exact address in a mock app in Teams, and it's working fine - appearing in the tab, and showing my name as per your code. Did you take out the "validDomains" items?

Comment: It's weird. Yes i did remove it but still my app doesnt get load.i have used chrome browser this is my manifest file for the app [link] (https://pastebin.pl/view/ce63efd3)

Comment: that looks ok - can't see anyhting obvious. You can try remove "websiteUrl", and also the "index.html", but they really shouldn't show any difference. Are you being sure to redeploy the app when you make these manifest changes?

Comment: yes im deleting the app from my 365 teams admin center and uploading again. i changed the version too, just to be sure. would there be anything that wouldn't let the app to load in 365 portal settings? but m able to install it so maybe the settings should have been fine.

Comment: why are you not just using App Studio?

Comment: I am using the app studio to create and validate the manifest file. Validation of app's zip is fine in app studio but at the end it doesn't load in tab. I would be grateful if you could pass me the manifest file of the mock that worked for you using this url. i feel like i'm doing all goood and trying for last 7 days but still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try using App Studio to do the deployment directly as well. It's only going to affect your user account anyway, so it's quite sandboxed, and it's much faster for testing/iterating changes. Regards the manifest, rather post your own updated version

Comment: would there be any problem from https? im using a free valid certificate from let's encrypt

Comment: I don't think so - it's fine in the browser my side